# I can route into my components with their respective path name, so my login page doesn't make any sense

Tags: reactjs, mern

I need help!!!
I have multiple content that is to be rendered after login. I have successfully created the login page and it is working fine.
but i can render the components just by typing the path name in the url bar of my browser so my login page doesn't make any sense.

i have {dashboard, History , employee }
i can just render these components by typing /dashboard, /history without logging in

which should not work like that

```js
THis is my Login.jsx



import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import logo from "../../../Icons/logo.png";
import { useNavigate, useParams, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Login({ setusers }) {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    userName: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({
      ...user,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const login = () => {
    axios.post("/login", user).then((res) => {
      alert(res.data.message);
      setusers(res.data.user);
      history.push("/dashboard")
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="tskms_login-container">
        <div className="tskms_login-container-left">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="tskms_login-container-right">
          <p>Login</p>
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="userName"
              value={user.userName}
              onChange={handlechange}
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={user.password}
              onChange={handlechange}
              placeholder="Password"
            />

            <h5>Forgot Password?</h5>
            {/* <NavLink to={"/dashboard"}> */}
          </form>
          <button className="tskms_login-right-btn" onClick={login}>
            Login
          </button>
          <div></div>
          {/* </NavLink> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

this is my app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Components/After Login/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Task from "./Components/After Login/Task/Task";
import Employee from "./Components/After Login/Employee/Employee";
import History from "./Components/After Login/History/History";
import Notification from "./Components/After Login/Notification/Notification";
import Popup from "./Components/After Login/Task/Popup";
import Addemploye from "./Components/After Login/Employee/Addemploye";
import EmployeeCard from "./Components/After Login/Employee/EmployeeCard";
import Login from "./Components/Before Login/Login/Login";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [user, setusers] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            user && user._id ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <Login setusers={setusers} />
          }
        />

        <Route path="/login" element={<Login setusers={setusers} />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/task" element={<Task />} />
        <Route path="/createtask" element={<Popup />} />
        <Route path="/employee" element={<Employee />} />
        <Route path="/history" element={<History />} />
        <Route path="/notification" element={<Notification />} />
        <Route path="/employee" element={<Addemploye />} />
        <Route exact path="/employee/:id" element={<EmployeeCard />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add HOC component, which will detect if there is authz token. If there is not, you can display information like: 'You need to be logged in to enter this page'.

For example:

```
export default withDashboardHocs(Dashboard)
```

And HOC component would look like:

```
export default function withDashboardHocs<C>(
WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<C>,
redirect = '/login'
) {
return (props: C) => {
const router = useRouter();
const [authzResult] = "API WITH AUTHZ TOKEN"();
const { data, fetching, error } = authzResult;

if (error) {
  router.push(redirect);
}

if (fetching) {
  return null;
}

if (!data) {
  return null;
}

const whoAmI = data.AuthWhoAmI;

return (
  <UserContext.Provider value={whoAmI}>
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  </UserContext.Provider>
       );
 };
}
```